# the timer can not be connected to the slot in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I can not connect the timer to the move() slot
`timer.timeout.connect( self.move)` this is not working
but `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, self.move)` this is just working one step not more.

```
class Bullet(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setRect(0,0,10,50)

        #timer = QTimer()
        #timer.timeout.connect( self.move)
        #timer.start(50)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, self.move)

    def move(self):
        print("Timer Clicked")
        self.setPos(self.x(), self.y()-10)
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is simple, a variable created in a function is local and will be eliminated when the function is finished, therefore the signal does not fire, instead the `QTimer.singleShot()` has a global scope, the solution is to extend the scope of the timer, for this you must make it a member of the class.

```
class Bullet(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setRect(0,0,10,50)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move)
        self.timer.start(50)

    def move(self):
        print("Timer Clicked")
        self.setPos(self.x(), self.y()-10)
```

Comment: hmm yea that was the problem tanxx