# PYQT5 webcam is not opening on the label

Tags: pyqt5, webcam, opencv, python

I am trying to set my webcam to a label and open it on pageload. However code does not throw any error also it does not getting bind to the label as well. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'camera.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,qApp
import sys
import cv2

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(169, 59, 471, 251))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.capture = cv2.cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.setInterval(int(1000/30))
        timer.timeout.connect(self.get_frame)
        timer.start()        

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def get_frame(self):
        frame = self.capture.read()
        image = QtGui.QImage(frame, *frame.shape[1::-1], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
      


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `timer` is a local variable and gets out of scope (aka: deleted) right after `setupUi` returns. Change all its references to `self.timer` (see [the timer can not be connected...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442487/the-timer-can-not-be-connected-to-the-slot-in-pyqt5)). Also note that `capture.read()` is blocking, so if the output is not ready your program will probably freeze. Finally, as clearly stated in the header of that file, you really should **never** edit files created by pyuic. Read more on [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: yap that was the issue. Thanks a lot for helping me out. BTW i actually use designer initially after that . i just manually edit the code always. IS there any other reason to not do it other than risk of replacing code?

Comment: The main reason: at a certain point you might need to modify the UI, maybe because you want to rearrange widgets, change sizes, add other widgets to provide more features: the result is that merging the new pyuic output with code you've already written will *always* be hard and painful, as you'll need to restore all functions and ensure that any reference to previous widgets is still correct. Then there's the class issue: subclassing from a Qt class allows overriding (for instance, override `closeEvent` to show a message box before quitting), while editing the pyuic class makes it much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that timer is a local variable that will be destroyed so the get_frame method will not be invoked, the solution is to make it a member of the class so you must change `timer` to `self.timer`. Also the read() method returns a tuple, no the frame so you should change it to:

```py
def get_frame(self):
    ret, frame = self.capture.read()
    if ret:
        image = QtGui.QImage(
            frame, *frame.shape[1::-1], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888
        ).rgbSwapped()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: I have change the code you have suggested but still label does not get bind to camera.

Comment: i think the issue is with Timer is  set as the local variable also. I set it as self.timer and and your code and  it fixed the problem . Thanks eyllanesc.

Comment: @NipunAlahakoon I clearly indicate that you should switch to self.timer